# Slack API upload image or video

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I am learning slack API to create a bot using howdy botkit.  I am trying to implement upload image/video functionality using upload button. I don't have any idea how to implement. I have gone through few articles but doesn't works for me. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with the mentioned botkit, but in general you can upload images to Slack using the Slack API method [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) method. This call will return a `file ID`, which you can then use for other file-related API methods. This works great with images (e.g. gif), I have not tried this with video though.

Looking at the howdy botkit [documentation](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/readme-slack.md#using-the-slack-web-api) and main [code](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/lib/Slack_web_api.js) it does support all common Slack API methods including [file.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload). The syntax should be something like this:

```
bot.api.files.upload({},function(err,response) {
  //Do something...
})
```